# Windows NTFS Drives not Read-Only

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

I am currently live-booted into Ubuntu 17.10.1

There are three internal hard drives plugged into the system:

1. WD 320GB - A (contains Windows 10)
2. WD 1TB - B (blank)
3. WD 2TB - C (contains 1.6TB of media)

My objective is to switch completely from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, as this desktop isn't used as much, and Ubuntu works better for simple data transfer (Drive C is used mostly for backups).

I had faced problems with drive permissions before, and therefore wanted to make sure everything works on a live boot before installing Ubuntu.

**The Problem** I am facing now, is that A and C are mounted as read-only. I can access all the data without a problem, but even when I tried to change the permissions to Read and Write and Create and Delete on a particular folder, although it did not show any error, no changes were made (I still could not create a new folder within that folder, nor delete any files).

I have checked similar questions, but ntfs-3g is already installed, but there is no change.

What can I do to make all my drives read and write, without losing any data?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are you mounting the drives?  Automatically, via `/etc/fstab` entries, or by clicking them in the GUI?  (We need more information of how you're trying to open the drives)

Comment: I clicked them in the GUI, after selecting '+ Other Locations' in the sidebar

Comment: I opened gparted as well, from there I can't even mount the two drives. Only the 1TB drive is read-write and mountable from gparted, but that is probably because I formatted it on the live-boot itself (with a new partition table and all)

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of what you see in gparted to your question?